# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.6 (from versions: )

Tags: command-line, python, django

I am following a tutorial on https://djangogirls.org/ and I am frustratingly running into issues installing django or any other package. Per the tutorial, after creating and activating a Virtual Env, I was instructed to create a requirements.txt file in the project folder with the following line:

```
Django ~= 2.0.6
```

This always leads to this error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django~=2.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django~=2.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

I'm not sure what is going on. I also tried:

```
python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade Django==2.0.6
```

But I also get:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.6 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.6
```

Please help. I can't continue the tutorial without resolving this. thank you

Comment: Did you update your version of pip?  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`  Also, Django is beyond version 3 now---almost ready to release version 4 by year end.

Answer (score 0):

If yop ur a MAc user follow the steps:

**STEP ONE**

Create a directory for your project & install virtual env.

```
mkdir projects
cd projects
python3 -m venv myprojectvenv
```

**STEP TWO**

we will activate the virtual env

```
source myprojectenv/bin/activate
```

Output

```
(myprojectenv) .....
```

**STEP THREE**

Will install Django in our virtual environment .

```
(myprojectenv)$ pip3 install django
```

This will install the latest Django version. if you need a specific version then you can run

```
(myprojectenv)$ pip3 install django==2.0.5
```

Make sure you install Django in your active virtual env. Also if you need to check what packages you have installed, you can run:

```
pip freeze
```

Hope this works with you.